Authentication Required -
I've joined a Linux OS to the AD domain and added AD groups to the sudoers file. Everything is working fine, but a Windows-like authentication box appears when performing certain tasks that require sudo privileges. In the dropdown menu, no AD users are listed—only users who have been individually added to the sudoers file.
I tried adding my own AD domain user individually, and then it appears in the dropdown menu, even though the AD group has already been added to /etc/sudoers.
It's very time-consuming to add each AD user individually to the sudo group.


Are you adding those users to the sudoers file or to the sudo group?

That's not a sudo dialog. It is a policykit dialog, which has its own authorization system that just happens to be pre-configured by your distribution to use the same group as 'sudo'.
Its equivalent of "sudoers" file is JavaScript-based /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/*.rules as documented in the polkit(8) manual page. For example, if you want to give "admin" rights to a specific group, you would use addAdminRule():
polkit.addAdminRule(function(action, subject) {
    return ["unix-group:wheel"];
});


thanks for your reply  ,
but there are almost 100 AD domain users , the drop down menu only shows users which has been added individually to sudoers group ,though i have already added AD Domain GROUPs in sudoers .

Yes, but I mean, I just said in the post that the drop-down menu has nothing to do with sudo and will not care about your sudoers file.
